# dlv attach to Go runtime process that binary is built with go build -ldflags="-s -w"

Tags: go, gdb, delve, go-build

I want to debug with **dlv** in runtime. However, our binary is built with `ldflags="-s -w"`, is there any way to recover/load the symbol table and debug information? I cannot build another binary for the situation I want to check would no longer exist once I stop the process.

[environment]

```
go version: 1.21.6 linux/amd64
Go process run in a container
```

[build command]

```
go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o server cmd/server/main.go
```